# How to retrieve mobile numbers from iPhone Contacts.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, contacts

I use the following code to set the retrieve the phone number in my app.

```
CFStringRef addressBookMobile;
ABRecordRef person;
NSString *mobile;

person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
addressBookMobile = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
mobile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", addressBookMobile];
```

The tag of the contacts is 'mobile'. However, when I use the `NSLog(@"%@", mobile);` . It displays the `<NSCFType: 0x802ffc0>`. does any problem for my code?

Should I use the `const CFStringRef kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel` and how to use? As if I replace it as the above code, it has the error. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
CRStringRef mobileNumber;
CRStringRef mobileLabel;
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
    mobileLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
    if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Mobile>!$_"]) {
        mobileNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers,i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

check the ABPerson Refrence and You need't use @"*$!!$*" but kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel. the example is:

```
    ABMultiValueRef phones = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSString* mobile=@"";
    NSString* mobileLabel;
    for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
        //NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
        //NSLog(@"%@", phone);
        mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
        if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel]) {
            NSLog(@"mobile:");
        } else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel]) {
            NSLog(@"iphone:");
        } else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhonePagerLabel]) {
            NSLog(@"pager:");
        }
        [mobile release];
        mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
        NSLog(@"%@", mobile);
    }
```

Comment: why it shows me error on this line ABMultiValueRef phones = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSString* mobile=@""; says undeclared person. i am using ios 5

Answer (score 5):

The phone numbers of a person in the Address Book are in the form of a multi-value property.

In your case, you should have something like the following (haven't tried it, typing directly here, so I don't know if it compiles and/or works):

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSString *mobileNumber;
NSString *mobileLabel;
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
    mobileLabel = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(mobilePhones, i);
    if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"mobile"]) {
        mobileNumber = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mobilePhones,i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: lancu, thank you for your reply. But I find that the solution may incorrect. the result is the same and I want to ask, what is the mobilePhones in the code? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry Mark, it should have been phoneNumbers :-). As I said, I typed it directly in the form, not in Xcode :-). So instead of mobilePhones, replace with phoneNumbers and it should be all good.

Answer (score 0):

This is solid for ARC 64bit iOS8:

```
- (NSArray *)phoneNumbersOfContactAsStrings:(ABRecordRef)contactRef {

NSMutableArray *mobilePhones = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRef, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSArray *allPhoneNumbers = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phones));

for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [allPhoneNumbers count]; i++) {
    if ([(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, (long)i)) isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel]) {
        [mobilePhones addObject:CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, (long)i))];
    }
    if ([(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, (long)i)) isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel]) {
        [mobilePhones addObject:CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, (long)i))];
    }
}

CFRelease(phones);
return mobilePhones;
}
```